# I am getting an error says that undefined local variable or method 'blog_params' (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I got a very basic blog app running with three links to a blog post. However, when I click on a post of my selection and edit the post and click on "update blog", I will get an error saying NameError in BlogsController#update and undefined local variable or method 'blog_params' for blogscontroller. I cannot figure out what the issue is so I would like some help to guide me through

This is what my blogs controller file looks like

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @blogs = Blog.all
end

def show 
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
end 

def new 
  @blog = Blog.new
end

def create
  @blog = Blog.new
  @blog.title = params[:blog][:title]
  @blog.body = params[:blog][:body]
  @blog.save
  redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end

def destroy
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
 @blog.destroy
 redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end

def edit
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
end

def update 
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
@blog.update(blog_params)

redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def update 
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
**@blog.update(blog_params)**

redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end
```

here you are calling **blog_params** but you haven't defined it anywhere in your code.

See example here:
[See strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
#app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @blog = Blog.find params[:id]
      @blog = @blog.update blog_params
   end

   private

   def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body) #-> in "permit" put the attributes of your "blog" model
   end
end
```

The error is a standard programming issue - undeclared function.

---

Because you're starting - and to give you more context - the reason this is a problem is because you're calling `blog_params` when you run the `.update` method:

```
@blog.update blog_params
```

This, as mentioned by `Pardeep Dhingra`, is the [*strong params*](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) pattern introduced into Rails 4. Strong params prevents [mass assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) by explicitly permitting particular attributes of your model.

Whilst your code is okay, you lack the `strong params` method (in your case `blog_params`), which Rails needs to complete the request. Adding the method will fix the issue.